# Tables on first page float to top, how to move them to next page

Tags: tables

I am using the Neurips template, with its fancier bolded title section.

I immediately place two tables on the first page. They float to the top of the first page, above the title and authors section.

Forcing them in-place using [h] is undesirable because these 2 tables in a row cause huge gaps in spacing.

**So how do I specify them to be placed on the next page (or, NOT on the FIRST page)?**

> (Current google queries don't seem to yield an answer; existing questions are about page-breaking a long table in the middle, or **preventing** a table from moving to the next page)

Thanks!

EDIT: Thanks for kind suggestions. Here is the Minimal Working Example that reproduces the issue.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[preprint]{neurips_2021}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % allow utf-8 input
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    % use 8-bit T1 fonts
\usepackage{hyperref}       % hyperlinks
\usepackage{url}            % simple URL typesetting
\usepackage{booktabs}       % professional-quality tables
\usepackage{amsfonts}       % blackboard math symbols
\usepackage{nicefrac}       % compact symbols for 1/2, etc.
\usepackage{microtype}      % microtypography
\usepackage{xcolor}         % colors

\usepackage{float}    
\usepackage{graphicx}   
\usepackage{subfigure} 
\usepackage{caption}    
\usepackage{amsmath} 

\title{Minimal Working Example}

\author{%
  Abc\\
  \And
  Cde\\
}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
    blah blah.
\end{abstract}

% =========================================================
\section{Introduction}

\indent Hello world!

% =========================================================
\section{Another section}

\indent We did this and that. 

\begin{table}[]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{}llllllllll@{}}
\toprule
0    & 1    & 2    & 3    & 4    & 5    & 6    & 7   & 8    & 9    \\ \midrule
2.0  & 6.0  & 1.0  & 10.0 & 3.0  & 3.0  & 7.0  & 3.0 & 1.0  & 10.0 \\
2.0  & 6.0  & 1.0  & 10.0 & 3.0  & 3.0  & 7.0  & 3.0 & 1.0  & 10.0 \\
2.0  & 6.0  & 1.0  & 10.0 & 3.0  & 3.0  & 7.0  & 3.0 & 1.0  & 10.0 \\
2.0  & 6.0  & 1.0  & 10.0 & 3.0  & 3.0  & 7.0  & 3.0 & 1.0  & 10.0 \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{}llllllllll@{}}
\toprule
0    & 1    & 2    & 3    & 4    & 5    & 6    & 7   & 8    & 9    \\ \midrule
2.0  & 6.0  & 1.0  & 10.0 & 3.0  & 3.0  & 7.0  & 3.0 & 1.0  & 10.0 \\
2.0  & 6.0  & 1.0  & 10.0 & 3.0  & 3.0  & 7.0  & 3.0 & 1.0  & 10.0 \\
2.0  & 6.0  & 1.0  & 10.0 & 3.0  & 3.0  & 7.0  & 3.0 & 1.0  & 10.0 \\
2.0  & 6.0  & 1.0  & 10.0 & 3.0  & 3.0  & 7.0  & 3.0 & 1.0  & 10.0 \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

% =========================================================
\section{Another section}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I have a temporary solution where I can force the FIRST table in-place using [h]. This forces the second table to go onto the next page to the top, as desired. However, it seems odd to me that tables can float to above the Title and Authors sections on the first page, so I think this question is important and seems un-asked

Comment: It's very hard to provide any help or input with something like without a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) to test with ourselves.

Comment: Thanks! I've just added the MWE :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the the `neurips_2021.sty` file redefine the `\maketitle` command. But don't include the `\@topnum\z@` as the standard cls file (article, book...etc).

So you could put following contents before the `\maketitle` in your document to solve the problem:

```
\makeatletter
\@topnum\z@
\makeatother
```

Comment: Thank you! This seems to do the trick.

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

From your description, I guess a solution for you: You can use [hb] or [!hb] to force them at the bottom of the page.

Your MWE have no text. If you add the text then the table may change their position. So, add your text then relocate the tables.

Try this solution if it works:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[preprint]{neurips_2021}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % allow utf-8 input
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    % use 8-bit T1 fonts
\usepackage{hyperref}       % hyperlinks
\usepackage{url}            % simple URL typesetting
\usepackage{booktabs}       % professional-quality tables
\usepackage{amsfonts}       % blackboard math symbols
\usepackage{nicefrac}       % compact symbols for 1/2, etc.
\usepackage{microtype}      % microtypography
\usepackage{xcolor}         % colors

\usepackage{float}    
\usepackage{graphicx}   
\usepackage{subfigure} 
\usepackage{caption}    
\usepackage{amsmath} 

\title{Minimal Working Example}

\author{%
  Abc\\
  \And
  Cde\\
}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
    blah blah.
\end{abstract}

% =========================================================
\section{Introduction}

\indent Hello world!

% =========================================================
\section{Another section}

\indent We did this and that. 

\begin{table}[]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{}llllllllll@{}}
\toprule
0    & 1    & 2    & 3    & 4    & 5    & 6    & 7   & 8    & 9    \\ \midrule
2.0  & 6.0  & 1.0  & 10.0 & 3.0  & 3.0  & 7.0  & 3.0 & 1.0  & 10.0 \\
2.0  & 6.0  & 1.0  & 10.0 & 3.0  & 3.0  & 7.0  & 3.0 & 1.0  & 10.0 \\
2.0  & 6.0  & 1.0  & 10.0 & 3.0  & 3.0  & 7.0  & 3.0 & 1.0  & 10.0 \\
2.0  & 6.0  & 1.0  & 10.0 & 3.0  & 3.0  & 7.0  & 3.0 & 1.0  & 10.0 \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[!hb] %%%%%%%%%%%%% just added this line.
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{}llllllllll@{}}
\toprule
0    & 1    & 2    & 3    & 4    & 5    & 6    & 7   & 8    & 9    \\ \midrule
2.0  & 6.0  & 1.0  & 10.0 & 3.0  & 3.0  & 7.0  & 3.0 & 1.0  & 10.0 \\
2.0  & 6.0  & 1.0  & 10.0 & 3.0  & 3.0  & 7.0  & 3.0 & 1.0  & 10.0 \\
2.0  & 6.0  & 1.0  & 10.0 & 3.0  & 3.0  & 7.0  & 3.0 & 1.0  & 10.0 \\
2.0  & 6.0  & 1.0  & 10.0 & 3.0  & 3.0  & 7.0  & 3.0 & 1.0  & 10.0 \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

% =========================================================
\section{Another section}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks!! I've just added the MWE :)

Comment: Thank you. This solution is very simple and elegant. It does indeed work well. I actually don't have much text to add as I am required to get straight to the point :)  I've upvoted but I am too new for it to show up publicly as +1 :)